# Twitter Bootstrap Modal - IsShown

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog, twitter-bootstrap

Hello Fellow SO users,

Got this problem where i auto populate a modal box.

Sometimes it already has content, so i tried doing a hide/show on each request. 
But the show is fired before the hide function is done, so it breaks the script.

I can't do a bind to "hidden", because if it's the first time - it won't fire the hidden function from bootstrap.

Using modal('true') i can see the object has a isShown element, but does anyone know how i can access it?

The console.log shows this:

```
$backdrop
    [div.modal-backdrop]

$element
    [div#modal-from-dom.modal]

isShown
    true

settings
    Object { backdrop="static", keyboard=true, show=false}

hide
    function()

show
    function()

toggle
    function()

__proto__
    Object { toggle=function(), show=function(), hide=function()}
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

**Answer for Twitter Bootstrap 3:**

```
$("element").data()['bs.modal'].isShown
```

**or**

```
$("element").data('bs.modal').isShown
```

Answer (score 11):

The answer is:

```
$("element").data('modal').isShown
```

Comment: But you cannot check this way if you've never shown the modal before. This only works if you have already once opened a modal window. Limited way.

Comment: if ($("element").data('modal') && $("element").data('modal').isShown) { worked fine for me }

Answer (score 3):

**On bootstrap 3.0.x**

```
  $('#modal_Id').data().modal.isShown
```

or

```
  $('#modal_Id').data('modal').isShown
```

modal_id is the id of your modal

Answer (score 1):

**If you'd like a Bootstrap version 2 *and* 3 solution** and would rather not hit the `data` (since it looks like the name already changed once)...

`$(element).hasClass('in')` (would be "faded in" or "visible"; a plus that it returns a boolean)

or

`"false" === $(element).attr('aria-hidden')` (so that's aria-hidden or visible as well. `"true"` for hidden in this case.)

See [source from bootstrap 3.3.1 here](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/c2c19a4d2d45d8ccb5c84d293dea35a94148c9a4/js/modal.js#L79):

```
this.backdrop(function () {
...
  that.$element
    .addClass('in')
    .attr('aria-hidden', false)
...
```

Again, that code is from 3.3.1.  Can confirm this also works in 2.1.0.  Duck sniffing [sic] is probably better in this case.

Answer (score 0):

**Answer for Bootstrap 4:**

```
$("element").data('bs.modal')._isShown
```

**As a function:**

```
function isModalShown(modal) {
    var modalIsShown = (modal.data('bs.modal') || {})._isShown;
    return !(typeof modalIsShown === 'undefined' || !modalIsShown);
}
```

Comment: I'm just checking if modal has 'shown' class, is this better in some way? It works as expected for me ..

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
$('#mymodal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
    console.log("Modal is shown");
//your other codes here...
})
```