# How to check if bootstrap modal is open, so I can use jquery validate?

Tags: jquery, validation, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I need to make a validation only if a modal is open, because if I open it, and then I close it, and the I press the button that opens the modal it doesn't work because it is making the jquery validation, but not showing because the modal was dismissed.

So I want to ad a jquery if modal is open so the i do validate, is this possible?

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

var validator =$('#form1').validate(
 {
  ignore: "",
  rules: {

usu_login: {
  required: true
},
usu_password: {
  required: true
},
usu_email: {
  required: true
},
usu_nombre1: {
  required: true
},
usu_apellido1: {
  required: true
},
usu_fecha_nac: {
  required: true
},
usu_cedula: {
  required: true
},
usu_telefono1: {
  required: true
},
rol_id: {
  required: true
},
dependencia_id: {
  required: true
},
  },

  highlight: function(element) {
$(element).closest('.grupo').addClass('has-error');
        if($(".tab-content").find("div.tab-pane.active:has(div.has-error)").length == 0)
        {
            $(".tab-content").find("div.tab-pane:hidden:has(div.has-error)").each(function(index, tab)
            {
                var id = $(tab).attr("id");
        
                $('a[href="#' + id + '"]').tab('show');
            });
        }
  },
  unhighlight: function(element) {
$(element).closest('.grupo').removeClass('has-error');
  }
 });

}); // end document.ready

</script>
```

Answer (score 221, accepted):

```
// For Bootstrap 5
$('#myModal').hasClass('show');

// For Bootstrap 3 and 4, to avoid the race condition @GregPettit mentions, one can use:

($("#myModal").data('bs.modal') || {})._isShown    // Bootstrap 4
($("#myModal").data('bs.modal') || {}).isShown     // Bootstrap <= 3

// or, with the optional chaining operator (?.)
$("#myModal").data('bs.modal')?._isShown    // Bootstrap 4
$("#myModal").data('bs.modal')?.isShown     // Bootstrap <= 3
```

as discussed in [Twitter Bootstrap Modal - IsShown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8755561).

When the modal is not yet opened, `.data('bs.modal')` returns `undefined`, hence the `|| {}` - which will make `isShown` the (falsy) value `undefined`. If you're into strictness one could do `($("element").data('bs.modal') || {isShown: false}).isShown`

Comment: There is a problem with this, if the modal isnt open, you will get 'undefined' from $("element").data('bs.modal')

Comment: ._isShown worked for me, i am using bootstrap 4 alpha

Comment: In Bootstrap 4, it's `_isShown`, not `isShown`.

Comment: I'm just checking if modal has 'shown' class (bootstrap 4) - works as I need it. Is checking _isShown better in some way?

Comment: Can you please share the solution in typescript ?

Comment: @trainoasis I'm not seeing `shown` class in BS4 modal when shown but can see `show` as per `user5490177` answer below

Answer (score 98):

You can also directly use jQuery.

```
$('#myModal').is(':visible');
```

Comment: Like when the answer are simple. If using ajax, I use this in the onbefore and check and return false, that way this also prevents multiple calls to the server. Thanks!

Comment: The accepted answer returned undefined or null. This worked flawlessly. Thanks!

Answer (score 94):

You can use

```
$('#myModal').hasClass('in');
```

Bootstrap adds the `in` class when the modal is open and removes it when closed

Comment: This turns out to be a bit fragile with the fade option and fast clicks or triggering a modal via an Ajax call. The time delay on the fade can create race conditions. Still, a useful way to hook into it when the contents are static and the model only pops up during user interaction!

Comment: The safest, surest way to avoid a race condition on a Bootstrap modal is to subscribe to its `shown.bs.modal` or `hidden.bs.modal` events. That way, when your event code gets control, you're dead certain the dialog isn't in a touchy state.

Comment: Is it Valid in Bootstrap version 4?

Comment: @MahdiAlkhatib No, this doesn't work in Bootstrap 4. You could replace `'in'` with `'show'` for Bootstrap 4.

Comment: @PhilipStratford show is also not working. see example: alert('before: '+$('#imagegalleryOneModal').hasClass('show'));
    $('#imagegalleryOneModal').modal('show');
    alert('after: '+$('#imagegalleryOneModal').hasClass('show')); I am getting 'false' in response in both before and after cases in bootstrap-4. Any suggestion? Thanks.

Comment: It's simply that your "after" alert is being triggered before the modal has finished being shown so it still returns false. See [this demo](https://www.codeply.com/p/p9JfRoinKa) I've made which demonstrates the point. This works because the test for `hasClass('show')` is called in the `shown.bs.modal` event, after the modal has been shown.

Answer (score 19):

**Bootstrap 2 , 3** Check is any modal open in page :

```
if($('.modal.in').length)
```

compatible version **Bootstrap 2 , 3 , 4+**

```
if($('.modal.in, .modal.show').length)
```

Only **Bootstrap 4+**

```
if($('.modal.show').length)
```

Comment: I am using Bootstrap `4.1.3` and it adds `show` class instead of `in`.

Answer (score 14):

Check if a modal is open

`$('.modal:visible').length && $('body').hasClass('modal-open')`

To attach an event listener

```
$(document).on('show.bs.modal', '.modal', function () {
    // run your validation... ( or shown.bs.modal )
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I used this to create an optimize function that closes all open modals.  `$(".modal:visible").modal("hide");`

Answer (score 11):

You can also use

```
$('#myModal').hasClass('show');
```

Comment: this worked on me for Bootstrap 5

Answer (score 4):

```
$("element").data('bs.modal').isShown
```

won't work if the modal hasn't been shown before. You will need to add an extra condition:

```
$("element").data('bs.modal')
```

so the answer taking into account first appearance:

```
if ($("element").data('bs.modal') && $("element").data('bs.modal').isShown){
... 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Why complicate things when it can be done with simple jQuery like following.

```
$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
    console.log('myModal is shown');
    // Your actual function here
})
```

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript Approach to check for any particular model state by its ID.

```
modalstate = document.getElementById('modal-id').classList.contains('show')
```

This will returns true if particular modal-id is open.

Answer (score 1):

this code indication, when modal is open(in body), or close (result false)

```
var trueFalse = ($('body').hasClass('modal-open'));
```

Comment: i'm, used when insert credential in screen, (for modal) and, the pag refresh 2 minuts, and, the refress or no refresh , drop all layer an not time for loggin... and serch , and costruction the solutions,... so long friend

Answer (score 0):

On bootstrap-modal.js v2.2.0:

```
( $('element').data('modal') || {}).isShown
```

Comment: Answer tested, original credits to the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21341587/1159167)

Comment: Why is this downvoted? It was precisely what I needed

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround I personally use a custom global flag to determine whether the modal has been opened or not and I reset it on '*hidden.bs.modal*'