# Bootstrap 3 Modal: how to check if modal is open or closed using jquery/javascript

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

Can anyone please tell me how to check bootstrap 3.0 modal status, is it open or closed using jQuery or javascript. I used following code but it works when you have opened a modal for one time otherwise gives data undefined error.

```
if($('#addMemberModal').data('bs.modal').isShown == true){
console.log("Modal is open");
}
```

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/a/21341587/1781706, looks like this answer figured out how to get around this undefined error.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You can also use straight jQuery like this:

```
$('#myModal').is(':visible');
```

Answer (score 28):

you can refer to their page
http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals

```
$('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
  // do something...
})
```

**show.bs.modal**
This event fires immediately when the show instance method is called. If caused by a click, the clicked element is available as the relatedTarget property of the event.

**shown.bs.modal**
This event is fired when the modal has been made visible to the user (will wait for CSS transitions to complete). If caused by a click, the clicked element is available as the relatedTarget property of the event.

**hide.bs.modal**
This event is fired immediately when the hide instance method has been called.

**hidden.bs.modal** 
This event is fired when the modal has finished being hidden from the user (will wait for CSS transitions to complete).
loaded.bs.modal This event is fired when the modal has loaded content using the remote option.

Comment: You could also check for the css class $('.modal').hasClass('in')

Answer (score 3):

try checking:

```
if($("#addMemberModal").data('modal') && $("#addMemberModal").data('modal').isShown ) {
    console.log("Modal is open");
}
```

or

```
if( $('#addMemberModal').hasClass('in') ) {
    console.log("Modal is open");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if the modal is opened in a form loaded by ajax you can use

```
$(document).on('hidden.bs.modal', '#photoModal', function () {
    cancel_camera();
    document.getElementById('PhotoPerson').innerHTML = '<img src="' +  photoPerson + '"/>';
});*
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the following code for my AJAX Call. After a setTimeout i tried to close the model properly and used the is() method for doing so. Hope it helps somebody.

```
complete: function(){
        setTimeout(function() {
            // model
            if($('#mdlNewOrder').is(':visible')) {
                $('#mdlNewOrder').modal('toggle');
            }
            //buttons
            $('#btn_closeNewOrder').prop("disabled", false);
            $('#btn_NewOrder').prop("disabled", false);
            // table reload
            $('#table_patientlist').DataTable().ajax.reload(null, false);
        }, 2800);
    }
```