# Check if Bootstrap Modal currently Show

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

I'm trying to combine the [Keypress plugin](http://dmauro.github.io/Keypress/) with [Modal dialogs in Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals).  Based on this question, I can [check if modal is open or closed using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24949383/).

However, I need to execute Keypress *only* if modal is closed.  If it's open, I don't want to listen for keypresses.

**Here's my code so far**:

```js
if(!$("#modal").is(':visible')) {

  var listener = new window.keypress.Listener();

  listener.simple_combo("enter", function() {
    console.log('enter');
  });

  // I have over 20 other listeners
}
```

Comment: I think you need to check if the modal is visible inside the event functions rather than creating the listeners when it's not visible. Unless the Keypress library changes this behaviour somehow, the listeners are now created on page load if the modal dialog is not visible and are always active.

Comment: Oh yes thanks its working but i have many listener u think is the best solution to check always ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's probably easier to leave the listeners attached and then conditionally exit them if the modal is open.

You could setup something like this:

```
var modalIsOpen = false
$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function(e) { modalIsOpen = true;})
$('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function(e) { modalIsOpen = false;})
```

Then just copy and paste the following line into all of your listeners.

```
if (modalIsOpen) return;
```

#### Demo in Stack Snippets

```js
var modalIsOpen = false
$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function(e) { modalIsOpen = true;})
$('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function(e) { modalIsOpen = false;})

var listener = new window.keypress.Listener();

listener.simple_combo("s", function() {
  if (modalIsOpen) return;
  alert("You hit 's'");
});
```

```html
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.rawgit.com/dmauro/Keypress/master/keypress.js"></script>


<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Don't Act On Key Presses</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        Try Hitting S
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<p>Try Hitting S</p>
```

Answer (score 4):

Bootstrap adds the `in` CSS class to a modal when it is open, thus (assuming your modal has `id="modal"`:

```
var modalIsOpen = $('#modal.in').length > 0;
```

Comment: Boostrap 4 adds a ``show`` instead of ``in`` - https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/#live-demo