# Execute javascript function in only one of multiple modals

Tags: javascript, function, iteration, bootstrap-modal

Well, here's the thing. I have two modals on my view. The first one called #modal1 and the second one #modal2.

I have a function named "a" that executes an "each" iteration that looks like this:

```
function a(input){
    var aKeys = new Array(),
        aValues = new Array(),
        sArray = {};

     $(input).each(function (index, element) {
            var sKey = $(this).attr('name'),
                sValue = $(this).val();
            aKeys.push(sKey);
            aValues.push(sValue);
        });

        aKeys.forEach(function (v, j) {
            sArray[v] = aValues[j];
        });

        return sArray;
}
```

Basically I'm trying to capture all the inputs inside the opened modal. It's working, but it's capturing both modals inputs. Any ideas on how to execute this code in only one modal? The one that's open?

Cheers.

Comment: Can you mention how are you calling this function ?

Comment: Normally, bootstrap modals, when they are not hidden have the classes `.modal.show` or `.modal.in` and would only have `.modal` when hidden. You can use this assumption to find the right modal. Check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19506672/how-to-check-if-bootstrap-modal-is-open-so-i-can-use-jquery-validate