# If modal is open then do not do a location reload

Tags: jquery, html

I'm looking to stop the page from reloading if there is a modal which is open.

Currently, I have an if statement which reloads the current page when a button is clicked.

But I need it to find the modal and if the modal is open then do not run the location reload.

```
if (isBasket) {
    location.reload();
}

<div id="optextrasModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Optional Extras</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="row">
                    <ul class="optionalExtrasBasket list-unstyled col-xs-12">
                        @foreach (var OEModel in Model.OptionalExtras)
                        {
                            foreach (var x in OEModel.ProductExtras)
                            {
                        <li class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 border-bottom optional-extra-row">
                            <div id="@("thank-you-" + x.ProductID)" class="optional-extra-thankyou text-center">
                                <div class="loaderBox"><img class="text-center" src="/Content/img/checked-icon.png" /></div>
                                <div class="margin-top">@x.Title</div>
                                <b>Has been added to your basket</b>
                            </div>
                            <div id="@x.ProductID" class="optional-extra-container">
                                <div class="optionalExtrasImage float-left margin-right">
                                    <a href="javascript:void(0);"><img class="img-responsive" src="@(@WebLocation.GetImageMedium(x.PrimaryImageUrl))" /></a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="optionalExtrasDetails float-right">
                                    <div class="title">@x.Title</div>
                                    <div class="price margin-top-half">@x.SalePrice.ToActiveCurrency()</div>
                                    <div class="stock-avail">@x.StockAvailabilityState</div>
                                </div>
                                <div style="display: inline-block; width: 100%;" class="margin-top">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input type="hidden" class="directProduct" id="directProduct" name="directProduct" value="@x.ProductID" />
                                        <label for="product" class="visible-xs">Button</label>
                                        <button style="width: 100%;" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-block js-buynow js-optional-extra" data-href="/ajax/AddToBasket?p=@x.ProductID" value="Add to Basket" data-text="Add to Basket" data-productid="@x.ProductID" title="Add to basket" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom">Add to Basket</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                            }
                        }
                        <!-- END LI -->
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer d-table" style="min-height: 80px !important; width: 100%;">

                    <div id="cart_total" class="vcenter text-left">
                        <span>@Html.Translate("Amount to Pay:")</span>
                        <span>@Html.Raw(Model.Basket.GetTotalCost().ToActiveCurrency())</span>
                    </div>
                <button type="button" id="secure-checkout" class="btn btn-secondary btn-lg" data-dismiss="modal">Secure Checkout</button>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

I'm thinking it will have to be written something like this ..

```
if ( ((isBasket)) && (!$("").hasClass("")) ) {
    location.reload();
}
```

Any help or suggestions would be great,

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Technically a modal should stop all interaction with the background while it's open. That's what 'modal' means, otherwise it's just a popup. This is a simple settings change, depending on which modal library you're using.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if bootstrap modal is open, so i can use jquery validate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19506672/how-to-check-if-bootstrap-modal-is-open-so-i-can-use-jquery-validate) - I'm presuming bootstrap due to classes used, obviously you could have created them yourself

Answer (score 0):

You could check to see if the display == "block".

```
var modal = document.getElementById("//ID of modal");


if(modal.style.display != "block")
{
    //Reload
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not mentioned which library you are using to open modal. If you are using bootstrap this might help you:

```
($("element").data('bs.modal') || {})._isShown    // Bootstrap 4
($("element").data('bs.modal') || {}).isShown     // Bootstrap <= 3
```

In case you are using other libraries please refer their Doc.