# Prevent keypress event listener from being triggered while bootstrap modal is open

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, ejs

I have a web app built using node, express, and ejs as the view engine. On a specific page I have an event listener that will go to the home page on key press, like so:

```
<script>
  document.addEventListener("keypress", function onPress(event) {
    window.location = ('/home');
  });

</script>
```

The issue is that I also have a button on that page that when pressed displays a bootstrap Modal element that includes input for text, so when the modal is open and the user tries to enter some input the event listener is triggered. Is there a way to ignore this event listener until the modal is closed?

I have tried giving a DOM (not containing the modal) a tabindex to make it selectable and putting the event listener on that, but then the user has to click on the page before the event listener can be triggered which is not ideal

Comment: You could use a boolean to keep track of the model state (true if open or false if close), and then put your `window.location = ('/home');` within an if checking if the `modalOpenState` is true or false.

Comment: @SiddharthBhansali I tried this by creating an onclick function that toggles the modal using jquery, this worked thank you

Comment: @SiddharthBhansali please can you post the answer it would be helpful for others thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way here would be to track the `modalOpenState` in a boolean variable. When the modal opens, set it to `true`, and `false` when closed. And when you're listening for the `keypress` event, check if the `modalOpenState` is true or false, and then redirect accordingly.

Note: As Zameer's comment also states, 'keypress' event is deprecated and can stop working any time. MDN suggests replacing it with `beforeinput` or `keydown` event as per requirement.

Answer (score 2):

You can prevent the `event` in `input` from propagating up towards to the `document` by using `event.stopPropagation` and then user input won't trigger the document `keypress` listener.

```js
document.addEventListener("keypress", function (event) {
  console.log("event", event);
  console.log("keyPress");
});

const input = document.getElementById("user-input");
input.addEventListener("keypress", function (e) {
  e.stopPropagation(); 
});

const btn = document.getElementById("hello-btn");
btn.addEventListener("click", function onClick(e) {
  console.log("clicked btn");
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Sample</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="app">
      <button id="hello-btn">Say hello</button>
      <input id="user-input" placeholder="enter text" />
    </div>
    <script src="src/index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

However, I would suggest not to attach the `keypress` event on `document`. As per MDN it's deprecated: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/keypress_event#browser_compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

you can use below snippet to check if modal is open or close.

```js
$('#myModal').hasClass('show');
```

For reference: [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19506672/how-to-check-if-bootstrap-modal-is-open-so-i-can-use-jquery-validate)

If the modal is open, just disregard the keypress event by returning. Alternatively, you can invoke the function if the modal is closed.

for eg:

```js
$(document).keypress(function (event) {
    if ($('#congratulationModal').hasClass('show')) return;
    else {
        if (event.key === "g" || event.key === "G") {
            functionCall("green");
        }
    }
});
```