# Bootstrap 3 Modal isShown

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8755561/twitter-bootstrap-modal-isshown) but I'm still in error!

Last Bootastrap 3.1.1

This is my modal

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                 <h4 class="modal-title">Storico</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">BLAH BLAH
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In javascript, I need to test if modal is shown or not

```
    if ($('#myModal').data('modal').isShown == true) {
        console.log("YEAH");
    }
```

I get:
**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'isShown' of undefined**

What is the right syntax?

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ric79/Hf27Q/)**

Riccardo

**POST**
I need to know the modal status. Is it displayed or not?

Comment: I came up with this function....
`function modalIsShown(id) {
    if ($("#" + id).data('bs.modal') == null) return false;
    else return $("#" + id).data('bs.modal').isShown;
}`

And then: 
`$("#myModal").modal('show');
console.log(modalIsShown("myModal"));`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if ($('#myModal').data('bs.modal').isShown == true) {
        console.log("YEAH");
    }
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Hf27Q/5/)

Comment: Thanks, but you added `$('#myModal').modal('show');`. If you remove that, the error raises up.
*** BETTER: I need to know the modal status? Is it shown or not?

Comment: In post what you read, answer #2 have comment 'But you cannot check this way if you've never shown the modal before. This only works if you have already once opened a modal window. Limited way'. Can do somthing like $('#myModal').modal('show'); $('#myModal').modal('hide'); on start, but it's looks not good. And don't forget change ..data('modal') to ...data('bs.modal'). Sorry, no ideas.

Comment: Alex Z: See my solution

Comment: Riccardo79: Ok. Thank you.