# multiple hidden.bs.modal events for multiple modal dialog

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I´m using modal dialogs, and I have the problem that when I close one of the dialogs, if I have 3 open already, using the 'hidden.bs.modal', it´s triggered  for all modal dialogs elements that I have on my DOM on that moment.
I would like to just catch the dialog closed. Any idea if it´s that possible?

```
$(element).on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
// do something…
})
```

Comment: I've never used multiple modals at the same time before. But if I'm understanding what you're saying, can you not just apply a unique ID to the modals and then target it in the jQuery "on" function instead of the hidden.bs.modal?

Comment: I´m afraid not, that event that I paste is in a generic js where does not know anything about dialogs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one way around this is to  get the states of the popups with isShown() as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8755561/twitter-bootstrap-modal-isshown) and hold you own list of popups for which the event has already been executed. the difference should be the current popup being closed.