# Treat enter keydown as pressing the "Next" button across multiple modals

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-modal

I have four modals that are each a step for filling out and submitting form. each modal has a "Next" button that closes the current open modal and opens the next in the process. I am trying to get the enter key to act as pressing the "next" buttons, and the "submit" button on the last step/modal.

This is my current code for a single modal(looks the same for all modals)

```
$("#user-lookup-modal").on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
    $('#add_assistant_submit').prop('disabled', true);
    $(document).keypress(function (e) {
        if (e.keycode == 13 || e.which == 13) {
            $('#add_assistant_next').trigger("click");
            return true;
        }
    }) ;
});
```

However, this causes weird behavior where pressing enter in one modal counts as pressing enter in all previous modals as well. I tested that out with console output.

EDIT:
I tried this, which seemed to work but is it a poor solution since it will listen for keypresses at all times?

```
$(document).keypress(function (e) {
            if ( e.keycode == 13 || e.which == 13) {
                if ($("#myModal").data('bs.modal') || {isShown: false}).isShown) {
                   //trigger button
                }
//... repeat for other modals

            }

        });
return false;
```

Comment: You should use a single keypress (actually: keydown) listener that handles all modals. My guess is that currently, you keep adding listeners to the document, so by the time the last modal pops up, pressing enter triggers four callback functions. A quick fix is to use [`unbind()`](https://api.jquery.com/unbind/) to remove the previous listener.

Comment: @ChrisG do you mean something like in the code i added in the edit? would that not be slow since everytime a key is pressed it will run all the `if` statements?

Comment: 1. you can check for the keycode at the very beginning and exit the function right away if isn't `13` ("slow" doesn't really apply to handling a single keypress, it's not like the function runs 60 times per second or the like). - - 2. `$("#user-lookup-modal").on('shown.bs.modal', ...` assigns an event listener; it cannot be used to test whether a modal is visible or not. Here's a way to do that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50718155/5734311

Comment: makes sense, i edited the code. I think that should work right?

Comment: Not as-is, there's a simpler way to find out whether a module is visible though: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/1axerj3s/